# How to access password from third-party provider such as vault or LastPass in google cloud composer?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, vault, lastpass

The Cloud Composer doesn't support SMTP password storage in environment,  according to the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#smtp_password) we can specify a command return SMTP password, I have tried bash command to export env var from airflow.cfg but failed to store password in airflow.cfg.

Our Gsuit credential is stored in LastPass, so the ideal way is to connect composer with lastpass to retrieve LDAP credential. Some applicable solution I can think of right now: 1) move credential from LastPass to Vault, enable vault in composer via ssh and use `vault kv get airflow/connections/smtp_default` in composer `smtp_password_cmd`; 2) create connections in airflow with LastPass and retrieve with airflow.hooks.base in code base (might need excessive config for security reason)  3) easiest way, hide hardcoded gmail password somewhere (not sure where thou)

Can someone point out a direction how to retrieve LDAP credential from third-party storage ( we don't want to use google secret at this moment) in cloud composer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing secrets backend or add your own custom secret backend if none of the secret backends is good for you. The existing backends you can use are vault, Google secrets, Amazon secrets, but rolling your own backend is super simple if none of the existing ones suit you.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html

In case of SMTP you need to define a connection (any type - http will do) which you have to specify via connection id (and the connection should have user/password for SMTP)